# laravel array_get first of multiple nested elements

Tags: php, laravel

i have an array, something like

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Jimmy
        [address] => Array
            (
                [number] => 1
                [street] => Astreet
            )
    )
```

I need to access [street] using something like helper `array_get` dot notation:

```
array.address.street
```

However, as it can have multiple elements, I need something like

```
array*
```

where it can just get the first one.

Coming from cakephp they have a helper so i can do

```
array.{*}.address.street
```

Is there something similar in laravel, i cannot find such

Comment: Do you want to get `street` from the first array element? or you want to get list of streets from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get street from the first element you can do:

```
array_get(head($array), 'address.street');

// or

array_get($array, '0.address.street')
```

And if you want to get list of elements that contains `street` you can use `array_pluck`:

```
array_filter(array_pluck($array, 'address.street'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$addresses = array_map(function($obj) {
    if ( array_key_exists('address', $obj) )
        if ( count($obj['address']) > 0 )
            return $obj['address'][0];
}, $yourArray);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you added some information as to why your answer solves the OP's issues and how does it work. This is a suggestion for this and future answers. Code-only answers are frowned upon. Thanks!

Comment: That may be true for some people, but there are a whole lot of programmers that don't even know what `array_map` does. Besides, if you add a description you get a more detailed answer (hence upvotes) and avoid the answer to go throught the Low Quality Posts review queue with a possible deletion.

Comment: Thanks for advice)